# Получить html код страницы c#

Tags: c#

При обычном запросе кода с сайта возникает исключение, при помощи Html agility pack он получает только javascript с редиректами, а если использовать браузер то все отлично, его несколько раз перенаправляет, приходится подгружать браузер и брать код из него. Можно ли обойтись без браузера?

Comment: _"Можно ли обойтись без браузера?"_ -- если часть html создается в javascript, то без браузера не обойтись.

Comment: Оба варианта вызывают исключения

Comment: _"Оба варианта вызывают исключения"_ -- какие? что в сообщении об ошибке?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Базовое соединение закрыто.Соединение было неожиданно закрыто, И второе вроде Ошибка шлюза 502.

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить html с помощью HttpClient и загрузить в Html agility pack.
Для того чтобы включить редирект, укажите AllowAutoRedirect = true

```
var h = new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = true };
var c = new HttpClient(h);
```

Или с помощью WebRequest так:

```
var r = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);    
r.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 5;
r.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```